# Option Selected Not Added in URL Paramater Using PHP

Tags: php

I want to add certain url parameter after submitting but it doesn't add it. Here's my effort:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $jml_produk = $_POST['jml_produk'];
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /bayar-sekarang/?jml_item=".$jml_produk.">";
    exit();
}
?>
```

And, the HTML is like this:

```
<form action="/bayar-sekarang/?jml_item=<?php echo $jml_produk; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank" id="frm_bayar">
<select name="jml_produk" id="jml_produk" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose one</option>
<?php
for($int=1; $int<=3000; $int++){
echo '<option value="'.$int.'">'.$int.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
```

The result I wish is like:

```
/bayar-sekarang/?jml_item=16
```

`16` above is just an example, but it gives me: `/bayar-sekarang/?jml_item=` only.

Comment: Why are you using a meta refresh for this in the first place? Why don’t you just make the form method GET to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe, I need to `$_POST` to grab the value and forward to other other url and grab the param in the URL. This is because security issue.

Comment: Why, what does this have to do with security? Are you planing on doing additional checks on the passed parameter value, that you did not show us? If not, then I don’t see how implementing an additional, superfluous step that just passes the value along as-is, would increase “security” in any way.

Comment: Apart from that you neglected to properly close of the value of the `content` attribute with a `'` at the end, I can’t currently see how this would fail.

Comment: I have tried using regular form and it got failed to add the param. Actually this form is used in amp web version. I use POST as a method but it told me about json problem can not parse line 28 where I use action-xhr. Now I use GET post and it works as I wish.

Comment: If the codes in my question can work, I can follow up my work to provide AMP in that web `https://www.jualbotolminum.com/beli-tumbler/?action=beli&item=arizona`

Comment: My question is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963911/amp-iframe-does-not-give-the-result-outside-amp-iframe` not solved yet - that is one of my effort to provide full amp in both desktop and mobile version. Finally, I use like current question.